# How can I implement the html code to upload a picture under the page title in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, css, html

I'm trying to put a picture that I uploaded in my Site Assets under the page title on SharePoint 2013. This is what I tried so far:

.ms-background-image{
background-image:url(https://collaboration-navy.forces.mil.ca/sites/navres-resnav/navreshq/cos-navres/sso-compt/WebISupport/SiteAssets/Forms/services-bi-header-2732x1536_2.jpg); 
}

Although, I don't think it's the correct class to add a picture on the top of the page only. 
I would need help to figure out which class this part is referencing too as well as the CSS and HTML code to implement the top background picture.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean you want to add "background" picture on the Page Title? Since SharePoint have various page templates, the page title could have different class name. Please provide more information and maybe a screenshot.

Comment: I would like to set a picture under the page title only, but not as a background.